# NoMethodError in PublicBundlesController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

In my web app a public_bundle has_many cards and a card belongs_to a public_bundle. I added the associations for this however, when I try to create a new public bundle I get a nothemod error saying undefined method 'cards' for the public_bundle.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password
   has_many :cards, through: :public_bundles
   has_many :cards, through: :bundles
   has_many :bundles
   has_many :public_bundles
end

class PublicBundle < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cards
   belongs_to :user
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :public_bundle
   belongs_to :bundle
end
```

Controllers:

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @card = current_user.public_bundles.cards.new
end

def create          
    @card = current_user.public_bundles.cards.new(card_params)
    if @card.save
        redirect_to '/'
    else
        render @public_bundle
    end
end

private 
def card_params
    params.require(:card).permit(:name, :description, :image)
end

class PublicBundlesController < ApplicationController

def show
    @public_bundle = current_user.public_bundles.find(params[:id])
    @public_bundle_edit = current_user.public_bundles.find(params[:id])
    @card = current_user.public_bundles.cards.new
    @cards = @public_bundle.cards.all
end

private
def public_bundle_params
    params.require(:public_bundle).permit(:name)
end
```

View:

```
        <div class="new-card">

        <%= form_for @card do |x| %>
            <%= x.text_field :name, :placeholder => " New Card Name", :style => "height:30px; width:530px; border:#ff4d4d solid; margin-top:14px; padding:5px; margin-left:14px; background-color:#eff5f5;" %>
            <%= x.text_field :image, :placeholder => " New Card Image (Optional)", :style => "height:30px; width:530px; border:#ff4d4d solid; margin-top:14px; padding:5px; margin-left:14px; background-color:#eff5f5;" %>     
            <%= x.text_area :description, :placeholder => " New Card Description", :style => "height:30px; width:530px; border:#ff4d4d solid; margin-top:14px; padding:5px; margin-left:14px; background-color:#eff5f5;" %>         
            <%= x.submit "✔", :style => "height:40px; width:40px; margin-top:10px; border-radius:100%; font-size:20px; background-color:#cce0ff; cursor:pointer; margin-left:270px;" %>                             
        <% end %>

    </div>
```

Comment: Add the error stack trace please.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with that term @ArupRakshit

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a new `@card` instance variable that way, Rails doesn't know which public bundle is going to be associated with the new card.

I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but you could try this in the cards controller:

```
def new
  @public_bundle = PublicBundle.find(params[:id])
  @card = @public_bundle.cards.build
end

def create
  @public_bundle = PublicBundle.find(params[:id])          
  @card = @public_bundle.cards.build(card_params)
  @card.user_id = current_user.id
  if @card.save
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render @public_bundle
  end
end
```